# Joint Density problem

Tags: probability

The joint density of X and Y is given by
$f_{x,y}(x,y) = ax+by$  if 0 < x, y<1, and 0 otherwise.

If EX$^2$Y = 11/48, find a and b

So I understand that the basic thing I want to do is solve
$\int_{0} ^{\infty}\int_{-\infty} ^1 x^2y(ax+by)dydx = \frac{11}{48}$
However when you work it to a point I end up with $\frac{1}{8}ax^4 + \frac19bx^3 ]_0^\infty = \frac{11}{48} $
So then I figure you want to set a and b to some form of $x^{-4}, x^{-3}$ respectively so that it doesn't go to infinity however that doesn't make sense to me. I also realize that I should probably utilize the fact that $\int_{0} ^{\infty}\int_{-\infty} ^1 (ax+by) dydx=1$, however this also has the same problem with infinite bounds.
Am I missing something else important? I feel like the bounds going to positive and negative infinity seems strange to me but I'm not sure.

Comment: $f_{x,y}(x,y)$ is 0 when $x \geq 1$ and when $y \leq 0$, so you have no infinite bound.

Comment: Integrate over the square, $x$ goes $0$ to $1$, $y$ goes $0$ to $1$. The integral of $ax+by$ being $1$ will give you one linear equation in $a$ and $b$. The other integral will give another linear eqquation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain is $0<x<1$, $0<y<1$. The way you've written the domain is simply a shorter way of writing it. If you use these bounds instead, you'll end up with a much nicer expression.

Comment: Oh of course I feel so silly misreading the bounds like that, thank you.